# CircleCI: Trigger build when repository that is not mine changes

Tags: continuous-deployment, circleci

At CircleCI: Is it possible to trigger a build when a git repository that is not mine changes / gets a new tag?

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a build via [the CircleCI API](https://circleci.com/docs/api/)

> POST: /project/:vcs-type/:username/:project/tree/:branch
>   Triggers a new build, returns a summary of the build.

Example:
`curl -X POST -H -d "{}" "https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/your_organization/your_project/tree/master?circle-token=3afeaxxxxxxxxxxx"`

Comment: Thanks! It is however not possible to trigger a build when something external happens, i.e. a new tag on github etc.